# Specific div elem for click event within view.when/view.on

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
view.when(function(){
    view.on("click", function () { doSomething = !doSomething;});      
});
```

The above works as a global click event. *HOWEVER*, I am trying to specify a specific div elem not a global elem. *i.e.* The logic I'd like:

```
view.when(function(){
    view.on("click", #myDivElm function () { doSomething = !doSomething;});        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a click event for the element itself.

```
var myElement = dom.byId("myElement");
on(myElement, "click", function(evt){
  doSomething = !doSomething;
});
```